# GvrAudioListener and GvrAudioSource not behaving as expected or at all

Tags: audio, spatial, google-vr

I must be missing somewhere. In the DemoScene.unity with an GvrAudioSource attached to a GameObject, I expect to notice it sounding different as I rotate the camera (with a GvrAudioListener attached) towards or away from the source, but it doesn't seem to sound any different.  If in the editor I move GvrMain camera rig away from and out of range of the GvrAudioSource (by adjusting one of the position parameters), I can still hear sound coming from the GvrAudioSource unchanged, whereas I would expect the volume to roll off with the "Volume Rolloff" parameter defined in the inspector of the GvrAudioSource script and be inaudible at distances greater then the "Max Distance".

I can't seem to get it working in either the DemoScene or my own scenes.

I am using Unity 5.3 and Windows 10, and the DemoScene.unity that comes with the Google VR SDK. I set the Spatializer Plugin to GVR Audio Spatializer in the Editor>Project Settings>Audio section, and am not getting any errors in the Console.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

For me what solved the problem (no audio at all), was to:

> Under Edit>Project Settings>Audio, is the Spatializer plugin set to Gvr?

from: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/222

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem for me - after setting the correct plugin - was lower down the "World Scale" value, in the "GVR Audio Listener" component.

Comment: What is "World Scale", GvrAudioListner does not have a "WorldScale" property.